# Retrieve value from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a login script with PHP. Users are redirected to it by a login form with username and password fields. My problem here is that mysqli `fetch_assoc()` does not return anything. I tried the same query on the database and it works as expected. I tried using `fetch_array` with mysql_assoc, or as numeric array but still no luck. I tried accessing with both `$row[0]` and `$row[password]` for the returned value, but when running I get the "no rows found, nothing to print", so I guess everything works good until that point.

Any hints as to what I might be missing?

```
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','site');

if(!$con)
{
die('Could not connect to database : ' . mysql.error());
}

$result=mysqli_query($con,'SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username="$_POST[iusrname]" LIMIT 1');

if (!$result)
{
    Die("Could not successfully run query from DB: " . mysql_error());
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
    die("No rows found, nothing to print");
}


if($_POST[ipwd] == '$row[password]')
{
echo "Authentication succeeded.You will be redirected to the main page shortly";
$_SESSION['loged']=true;
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST[iusrname];
}
else
{
die("could not authenticate user");
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: To format code you should select all your code and then press Ctrl+K, instead of a thousand backticks.

Comment: You're using single quotes to define your SQL string, which treats it as a literal; it's not interpolating the variables at all. Since you're using mysqli - why not make that SELECT into a prepared statement?

Comment: Fair warning: I'm going to downvote every answer that just sticks `$_POST['iusrname']` into SQL without even bothering to escape it.

Comment: did your password encrypted or simply inserted.if you using `md5` then you need to check it like `if(md5($_POST[ipwd]) == $row[password])`

Comment: security is not an issue this is not the final code, first i need to understand how it actually works and then i will refine it.You should not be so judgmental on somebodys first try on php/mysql... i know what needs to be done in theory, but my first priority is to make it work.As for the code formating i tried it that way and it does not let me post, i am using a mac and its not updated to later os, maybe there is something wrong with that...Thanks for the informative answers,ill try them out and ill see how ti goes.thank you all

Comment: @user2425942: My judgement is not directed at you; i don't expect someone asking questions like this to be totally up on security.  The people *answering* the question, though, should know better -- and should at least hint very, *very* strongly that it would be a good thing to escape stuff properly.

Comment: You are trying to use mysql.error() & mysql_error() while using mysqli_connect/mysql_query. Try using the correct function mysqli_error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing you query from this:

```
'SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username="$_POST[iusrname]" LIMIT 1'
```

to this:

```
'SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username='.$_POST['iusrname'].' LIMIT 1'
```

also you will have problems here:

```
if($_POST[ipwd] == '$row[password]')
```

should be:

```
if($_POST["ipwd"] == $row["password"])
```

and most likely here:

```
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST[iusrname];
```

that should be:

```
$_SESSION['user']=$_POST['iusrname'];
```

Comment: after fixing a range of things the above query still would not work properly but
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username='$_POST[iusrname]' LIMIT 1");
 works as intended

Comment: I forgot some quotes around iusrname, fixed.

Comment: Upvoting because this'll fix the problem at hand, but NOT because it's secure. This answer should point out in the strongest possible terms that Little Bobby Tables (in first two blocks) is unacceptable. http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

I spotted the error, I think.

In single quotes (`''`) PHP will not automatically replace variable names with variable values. Using double quotes should do the trick:

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['iusrname']); // For @cHao
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Username='$username' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: @cHao I thought that too, seeing the OP's code, but the paragraph at the top indicated this was the only error.

Comment: At the very least, you'd need to backslash those quotes around the variable.  But i was talking about the bigger issue, about which the OP appears blissfully unaware.  What happens when someone decides to say their name is `'' or role='admin'`...or something like that.

Comment: Nice catch about those quotes. But somebody else already mentioned prepared statements so I thought SQL injection had already been brought up. @cHao